# Export/Import const function with return res inside

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm struggling with a little function that I can't generalize.

```
const response = (status, value, message) => {
  return res.status(status).json({
    error: value,
    data: message ? message : null,
  })
}
```

if I put inside the

```
exports.endpointName = async (req,res) => {}
```

the function and the call function works properly (half working).

But I would like to have this function inside a global.js functions file and import it and call it as many times as need it.

Any clue of how do it?? I already try some ways as a function exports o exports.response, but no success.

Example of usagge with const inside the end point:

```
exports.checkDominioSiniestro = async (req, res) => {
  const response = (status, value, message) => {
    return res.status(status).json({
      error: value,
      data: message ? message : null,
    })
  }
  try {
    if (await vehiculo.findOne({ where: { dominio: req.body.dominio } })) {
      response(400, true, "Dominio is already in DB")
    }
    if (
      await vehiculo.findOne({
        where: { nro_siniestro: req.body.nro_siniestro },
      })
    ) {
      response(400, true, "Siniestro is already in DB")
    }
    response(200, false)
  } catch (err) {
    response(500, true, "Something goes wrong!")
  }
}
```

Comment: I meant half working because I have this error when is inside the async function and working as expected: 
(node:16068) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: Could you show how the `response` function is called in a normal scenario?

Comment: I call the function as `response(400, true, "Invalid request!")`

Comment: Ok and where does it get the `res` from right now? In which context is the `response` function declared?

Comment: @plalx added an example in the question

Comment: I recommend you to look at my answer which is more effective given you can preserve a simpler API where you don't have to provide the `res` for writing to it every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do that will be adding `res` object to the function parameters, when you define it in other file

```
const response = (res, status, value, message) => {
  return res.status(status).json({
    error: value,
    data: message ? message : null,
  })
}
```

Then when you call it, it could look in the following way.

```
response(res, 400, true, "Siniestro is already in DB")
```

Comment: Thanks man! It works! I define the function as `exports.response = function (res, status, value, message)` in a global functions file and call it many times as I want it

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at `response` we can see it requires a reference to `res` which is currently acquired through the parent function context. The way the `response` function is currently declared creates a closure over the parent's function context `res` variable.

If you want to reuse the `response` function in the same way you must be able to close over a different `res` instance for every request.

For instance, you could create a factory function like the following:

```js
fakeHandler({}, {});

// Factory function that creates a response writer for a given response
function responseWriterFor(res) {
  return (status, value, message) => {
     console.log(`write to res: ${status}, ${value} ${message}`);
  };
}

// Fake request handler just for the example
function fakeHandler(req, res) {

  // Create a new response writer for the given response
  const response = responseWriterFor(res);
  
  response('success', 'hello', 'world');
}
```

Even better, you could normalize the request handling in a way that the response writer gets provided automatically to the handling function context.

E.g.

```js
var checkDominioSiniestro = newRequestHandler((req, res, respondWith) => {
    respondWith('success', 'hello', 'world');
});

checkDominioSiniestro({}, {});


// Creates a request handler that gets injected a response writer
function newRequestHandler(handler) {
  return (req, res) => {
      handler(req, res, responseWriterFor(res));
  };
}

function responseWriterFor(res) {
    return (status, value, message) => {
        console.log(`write to res: ${status}, ${value} ${message}`);
    };
}
```

I left out the async for simplicity, but I believe you should get the idea ;)